# Drawing the floor tiles with html5 canvas but it is note perfect.how can i make realistic using webgl

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[image: this is the image]didn't look like a floor tiles. Some transformation / rotate / Angle was missing. How to do perspective view with html5 canvas

here is the code

```
function drawPattern(img, size, rectY) {
    var roomImg = new Image();
        roomImg.src = './assets/room2.png';
        roomImg.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(roomImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

        canvas.width = 1350;
        canvas.height = 600;

        var tempFloorCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var tFloorCtx = tempFloorCanvas.getContext("2d");
        tempFloorCanvas.width = size;
        tempFloorCanvas.height = size;
        tFloorCtx.drawImage(floorimg, 0, 0, floorimg.width, floorimg.height, 0, 0, size, size);
        tFloorCtx.setTransform(1,1,-0.5,1,30,10);
        tFloorCtx.rotate(50);
        tFloorCtx.fill();
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        

        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(tempFloorCanvas, 'repeat');
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.rect(0,400,canvas.width, 400);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();


        ctx.restore();

}

var floorimg = new Image();
        floorimg.src = './assets/tile5.jpg';
        floorimg.onload = function(){
            drawPattern(floorimg, 70, 0);
        }
```

If there is another solution to implement the feature or If there are third party plugins which can transform my canvas to some angle to be look like a floor of the room, then please let me know.

Comment: You are using the 2D API. Eg  `tFloorCtx = tempFloorCanvas.getContext("2d");` The 2D API as the name suggests does not do "perspective" transformations as that is a 3D operation. You need to use `"WebGL"` or add the tile perspective manually pixel by pixel.

Comment: i am new to html5 canvas. can you show me an example to how to do perspective transformation by using webgl ( sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box the HTML5 `CanvasRenderingContext2D` API does not offer a way to do perspective projection. There are some full-blown third-party libraries, foremost [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) that among other things let you do such kind of transformations.

However, if all you want to do is just perspectively distort an image it would be overkill to learn the Three.js API or even worse implementing it on your own using WebGL.

Luckily there is a tiny library called [perspective.js](https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/).

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let p = new Perspective(ctx, image);

  p.draw([
    [30, 0],
    [canvas.width - 30, 0],
    [canvas.width, canvas.height],
    [0, canvas.height]
  ]);
}
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1079/200/300";
```

```css
canvas {
  border: gray solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wanadev/perspective.js/master/dist/perspective.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: sir i want to make tiles visualization web app for tile manufacturers. how can i do that. i have a tile design image and a room image and i want to put tile image in room image as a floor by making pattern like realistic floor